async method has side effects that break JsonConvert.Serialization: Self referencing loop detected -- Path 'moveNextAction'
Weird async issue. I have a reasonably complicated set of mapping logic in a service for a WebAPI project. If I run the code as-is, I get an error like the following:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 
Self referencing loop detected for property 'target' with type 
'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[MyAppIncomeCore.Models.UserDto,MyAppIncomeApi.Controllers.UserController+<MapUserDto>d__63]'. 
Path 'moveNextAction'.

As best as my google-fu can tell, that's async related as in I'm probably not awaiting something somewhere.
The weird thing is that the async call that seems to be responsible for the error is doing nothing important. That is, I couldn't tell where I was going wrong, so I started returning the data transformation object I was mapping back early to see what operation was causing the error state.
Here's a code snippet from MapUserDto (the method mentioned in the error, above).
// ... lots of mapping stuff...

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.MyConnection?.AccessToken))
{
    model.MyConnection.AccessTokenValidTo = determineJwtExpiration(
        model.MyConnection.AccessToken
    );
}

var program = await _partnerRepository
    .GetProgramByReferrerKey(currentReferrer.ReferrerKey);

return model;

In the live code, program gets mapped to model in the following lines, but those don't get hit now because I returned the model early.
That gives me a error.
This does NOT:
// ... lots of mapping stuff...

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.MyConnection?.AccessToken))
{
    model.MyConnection.AccessTokenValidTo = determineJwtExpiration(
        model.MyConnection.AccessToken
    );
}

return model;

Okay, so there must be some weird side effect in that _partnerRepository.GetProgramByReferrerKey call, right? Here it is.
public async Task<Program> GetProgramByReferrerKey(string referrerKey)
{
    var partners = await _collection.FindAsync(
        x => x.Programs.Any(y => y.ReferrerKey == referrerKey)
    );

    return partners.FirstOrDefault()?.Programs
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ReferrerKey == referrerKey);
}


_collection is private readonly IMongoCollection<Partner> _collection;
IMongoCollection, to be clear, is from MongoDB.Driver.

And that var program in the original does return what seems to be a valid, hydrated object when I'm stepping through.
Even weirder, if I take the model that's returned from the service and try to JsonConvert "by hand", it's happy!
From my controller action:
var dto = await _myUserService.ExtendedMapToUserDto(
    // Removed a fair amount of parameters including some `Func`s. Don't hate.
    //
    // This call is to a method (`ExtendedMapToUserDto`) that normalizes 
    // the calls to the service method whose code is above.
)

// Okay, so we've got the dto. Let's serialize it.
var run = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(run); // <<< This is valid JSON!!!

return dto; // <<< Things blow up between here and Postman.

That's a really weird side effect for an async call.
Just for fun, I tried what was suggested here to remove reference loops and put this in Startup.cs' ConfigureServices in place of services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();:
services.AddControllers()
   .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
      options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
        Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

And got an even crazier error:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: This instance contains state that cannot be serialized and deserialized on this platform.
   at System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.OnSerializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)

// and it continues...

How should I be debugging this?

Self referencing loop detected is json related, nothing to do with async. Json serialisation requires a directed acyclic graph. But yours has cycles. This is why view objects exist, don't try to serialise your database objects directly. My guess is your trying to serialise some kind of mongodb collection, instead of a simple dictionary.

When async code seems to work when stepping debugging it usually means something isn't awaited. Your code is awaiting the async calls but move upwards as well to ensure the calling method itself was awaited properly all the way up. As for the self referencing Newtonsoft can be kind of weird with proxies and other data structure wrappers. I had something similar serializing an EF entity where there were no self-references/circular references yet Newtonsoft wouldn't work without ignoring reference loops.

@JeremyLakeman Okay, bad serialization was my first guess, but I never merge the program with the dto; I simply look program up if I stop the code as described above. I suppose there's a chance there's some interaction with the model -- perhaps the program returned is a descendent of the model? Is that your suggestion? (I'm new to the codebase and don't know the domain well yet.) And it serializes fine in that var run = line. Would services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson() (full stop) use different settings than JsonConvert.Serialize? :confused:

Your last stack trace; ClaimsPrincipal.OnSerializingMethod. So if the loop doesn't kill you, you end up trying to serialise HttpContext.User. Either you're returning completely the wrong value, or you have a property somewhere which should be [JsonIgnore]. Hard to say if you don't include the definition of your data classes.

@JeremyLakeman Good call. I dismissed that error simply as, "Well, the Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore trick didn't work."  Having ClaimsPrincipal in there is interesting and odd. I'm not at my workstation atm, and was having success just moving the code around in the little bit of time I hacked on it today. It currently lives in a project referenced by a project that's referenced by the API project. I think a number of odd things might be afoot that, as you say, may be impossible to guess simply from my OP. Thanks.
